# Click is not working in firefox headless while running in linux machine

Tags: java, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have a login page(simple login page with username/password and login button) for my application, on clicking of Login button in that page nothing is happening but i see the button got focused(i can see dots around the button in screenshot) and also ExpectedConditions.waitUntilElementIsClickable is returning me a webelement, but click method is not working on the same element.

Surprisingly when I run the same code in my windows machine it is working fine but the same code is failing in linux machine.

I have tried javascript executor, actions class, Keys.Enter, Keys.Return, added waits, thread.sleep but nothing worked for me.

Can someone please help me on this.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to set screen size parameter for the headless mode

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions

opts = FirefoxOptions()
opts.add_argument("--width=1920")
opts.add_argument("--height=1080")

driver = Firefox(options=opts)
```